# I am trying to use the Amazon SNS service but getting Unable to load credentials from any chain exception

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sns

I am trying to use the amazon sns service But getting Unable to load credentials from any chain exception.
Credentials are stored in application.properties file and i have also tried by storing the credentials in java system properties. But same error comes up.

com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@79a32e01: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint, com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@3d89f25d: profile file cannot be null]
at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:136) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1186) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.runBeforeRequestHandlers(AmazonHttpClient.java:776) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:719) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:701) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:669) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:651) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:515) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient.doInvoke(AmazonSNSClient.java:2488) ~[aws-java-sdk-sns-1.11.415.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient.invoke(AmazonSNSClient.java:2457) ~[aws-java-sdk-sns-1.11.415.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient.invoke(AmazonSNSClient.java:2446) ~[aws-java-sdk-sns-1.11.415.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient.executePublish(AmazonSNSClient.java:1848) ~[aws-java-sdk-sns-1.11.415.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient.publish(AmazonSNSClient.java:1820) ~[aws-java-sdk-sns-1.11.415.jar:na]
at com.appscms.aruba.core.event.listener.AccountModificationListener.listenToAccountModificationEvent(AccountModificationListener.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:312) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:197) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:160) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:426) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:383) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at com.appscms.aruba.web.controller.basic.AccountController.PatchupdateAccount(AccountController.java:58) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:880) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]

```
Bean for sns getting credendtials from properties file .

    public class SnsBean {
        
        private final SnsConfiguration snsConfiguration;
        
        @Primary
        @Bean
        public AmazonSNSClient getSnsClient() {
            var credentials = snsConfiguration.getPrimary();
            return (AmazonSNSClient) AmazonSNSClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2)
                    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                            new BasicAWSCredentials(credentials.getAccessKey(), credentials.getSecretKey())))
                    .build();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have not setup your creds properly. Once you do so, you can use the AWS SDK for Java within a Spring Boot app. To work with the AWS SDK for Java V2 (I'm answering this question with the recommended Java Version - which is V2), you need to choose one of the supported credential providers.

To read about the supported credential provider chains, see the ***Java V2 DEV Guide*** here:

[Using credential](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials.html)

Most of the examples in the [AWS Github example repo](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2) assumes that your credentials are located in a file named **credentials** located here:

- **Windows** - C:\Users<yourUserName>.aws\credentials
- **Linux, macOS, Unix** -  ~/.aws/credentials

Once you set a valid credential provider, you can create AWS Service client successfully using the AWS SDK for Java.

To help you with Amazon SNS and a Spring Boot app, there is an example of using the  Amazon SNS Service Java API V2 within a Spring BOOT app. This works well, as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

This shows the result of the **listSubscriptionsByTopic** method that belongs to the **software.amazon.awssdk.services.sns.SnsClient** object. Once you setup a credential provider, the **SnsClient** works fine in a Spring Boot app.

To learn how to successfully create an Amazon SNS app using Spring BOOT, see:

[Creating a Publish/Subscription Spring Boot Application](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_sns_sample_app)

Remember to place your creds in a file in the location specified above (or choose another way such as using **Environment variables** that is used in this Spring BOOT example).

Comment: Thanks smac2020 . I am able to solve this error by adding credentials to ~/.aws/credentials file but now i am getting another error  .com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.AmazonSNSException: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId; Request ID: b97736ae-8e46-5b0b-87ea-6f011f862460)

Comment: Try moving from V1 to V2.  Follow the code in that example above to see if you are able to successfully invoke SNS.